# Why the Oracle procedure not compiling?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ResetVersionNumberValue IS
  sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  FOR sql_stmt IN (select 'update '|| table_name ||
                          ' set version = 0'
                     from user_tables
                     where table_name like 'MY_%')
  LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Why the about procedure is not compiling? Its giving error saying

> Error(8,26): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to remember that when iterating a cursor it returns a ROW, not a VALUE, and
2. The SELECT in the cursor needs to give a name to the value in the row being generated by the cursor.

Try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ResetVersionNumberValue IS
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (select 'update '|| table_name ||
                          ' set version = 0' AS SQL_STMT
                     from user_tables
                     where table_name like 'MY_%')
  LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE aRow.SQL_STMT;
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ResetVersionNumberValue IS
BEGIN   
FOR sql_stmt IN ( 
        select 'update '|| table_name || ' set version = 0' as x 
        from    user_tables 
        where   table_name like 'MY_%')  
LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  sql_stmt.x;   
END LOOP;   
COMMIT; 
END;
```